# How do I access the User's HttpContext in OpenIdConnectEvents.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

In an ASP.NET Core App, I have code like the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options => ...)
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        ...
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            ...
            OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
            {
                // Here I want to access the user HttpContext. previously System.Web.HttpContext.Current
            }
        };
    });
    ...
}


}
```

My reason for needing access to the current User `HttpContext` is that I'm dealing with some `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` logic that caches access tokens in the user session. The previous version of the code used `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` which I understand has been removed from ASP.NET Core. `AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext.HttpContext` is clearly not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean `context.Request.HttpContext`?

Comment: Or just `context.HttpContext`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin @DavidG Are these the same `HttpContext`s that the controllers expose? (FYI I just need to be able to access the same session).

Comment: Yep, should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` parameter of `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` delegate contains `HttpContext` property that holds current http context

```
OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
{
    var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
    //..
}
```